# Regular Expression for email for a specific domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

This is my code:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmail" 
     runat="server" ValidationExpression="(\w+@[test]+?\.[com]{3})" 
     ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Email Id" 
     ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress" />
```

which is not working. But my problem does not end there. I would also like to know how to validate only characters in the username, and not numbers and special characters.

Please if anybody could help with this code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to format the code properly. (I did it this time for you)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z]+@yourdomain\.com$
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

At first I think there is a miss understanding of the square brackets. With `[com]{3}` you are createing a character class and match 3 characters out of this class, that means this will match `com` (I think as you wanted), but also `ccc`, `cmc` and so on.

Similar for `[test]+?`, this matches at least 1 character from `t`, `e` and `s`

When you say:

> validate only characters in the username, and not numbers and special
>   characters

I think you mean only letters? Or only ASCII letters?

What you meant is probably

```
(\w+@test\.com)
```

`\w` is a character class that contains A-Za-z0-9 and _ (and maybe anything thats a letter in unicode, I am not sure). If you want only ASCII characters then create your own character class with `[A-Za-z]`, if you want to allow any letter use the Unicode property `\p{L}`

Something like this

```
@"^(\p{L}+@test\.com)$"
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'm new to the coding world. I had serched a lot but could not find proper details about the topic. I'll keep this in mind from next time. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

`[test]` is probably not what you want. It's equivalent to `[tes]` and means 't' or 'e' or 's'.

Did you try something like:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+@.*\.com$
```

This will validate to emails of the form xxx@xxx.com

As C# literal this is `"^[a-zA-Z]+@.*\\.com$"`.

Comment: Can you please tell me the meaning of double backslash in your code?

Comment: in C# strings \ is a special character, so you need to escape it

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has an article about email validation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx

cheers

Comment: I have read it before and it was hardly useful in this regard. Thank You